# cleaner way of filling 0's in dynamic 2-D array in C++

Tags: c++

```
int **C = new int*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        C[i] = new int[cols];
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            C[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm creating dynamic 2-D array, but can we somehow initialize the array with 0's in all the entries without using inner loop?

Answer (score 5):

If you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, it would simply be

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> C(rows, std::vector<int>(cols));
```

Comment: Love it. Would be even more lovely if you specify the default value in the nested vector of cols i.e. `std::vector<int>(cols, 0)`. It just makes it clearer

Comment: @smac89 The default value for an `int` *is* `0`, so no need to explicitly specify that.

Comment: True, but not everyone knows that, and since OP probably wasn't using `std::vector` in the first place, there is a chance he doesn't know that either. Looks like it's called `value initialization`, thanks to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48725494/2089675)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

```
int **C = new int*[rows]();
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
  C[i] = new int[cols]();
}
```

However a std::vector would be nicer (because of memory management).

Comment: Why do you have to do value initialization here **C = new int*[rows]();? Can we not just do C[i] = new int[cols]();?

Comment: You are right. It is enough to do just C[i] = new int[cols]()

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [std::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) function:

```
int **C = new int*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    C[i] = new int[cols];
    std::fill(C[i], C[i] + cols, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::for_each(C, C + rows, std::bind(std::fill_n<int*, std::size_t, int>, _1, cols, 0));
```

Or if reused often:

```
auto fill_row = [] (int i) { return [=] (int* r) { std::fill_n(r, cols, i); }; };
std::for_each(C, C + rows, fill_row(0));
```